# How to override default resolver in Apollo Server if it automatically triggers Sequelize query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

Application uses Apollo Server and Sequelize as an ORM. I thought that every custom type needs a custom resolver, however in case of **Post** and **Author** types, post author is resolved automatically, therefore I cannot modify this logic to resolve N+1 problem.

Minimal example of schema could look like this

```
type Post {
  id: ID!
  author: User!
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
}
```

And resolver

```js
const postsResolver = {
  Post: {
    author: async (post) => User.findByPk(post.authorId)
  }
  Query: {
    posts: async () => Posts.findAll()
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I deleted **author** resolver, nothing has changed and it still returns author.

Is there any way to override default resolver?

These two objects do the exact same thing (which they shouldn't)

```js
// With author resolver
const postsResolver = {
  Post: {
    author: async (post) => User.findByPk(post.authorId)
  }
  Query: {
    posts: async () => Posts.findAll()
  }
}

// Without author resolver
const postsResolver = {
  Query: {
    posts: async () => Posts.findAll()
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. You're **already** overriding the default resolver by providing a resolver for `Post.author`. If you don't want to return an author at all, return null. If you want to avoid multiple calls to `User.findByPk`, use `dataloader`.

Comment: Yes, I do, but in the last paragraph I say that if I delete the resolver, it still returns author

Comment: @DanielRearden Description updated

Comment: Are you asking *why* you're seeing that behavior? In that case, you should include the Post and User models in your question.